# How to colour selected range of histogram matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a data named `prices`, and I use a `prices.tail(1)` to build a histogram.

Also I have some variables: `left_border = 341.086`, `right_border = 437.177`, `line_length = 1099`.

And the next code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))
plt.hist(prices.tail(1), bins = 400)
x2 = [left_border,left_border] 
y2 = [0, line_length]
plt.plot(x2, y2, color = 'green')
x3 = [right_border, right_border] 
y3 = [0, line_length]
plt.plot(x3, y3, color = 'green')

plt.show()
```

Produce an output:

[image]

How I can colour part of histogram which is between the green borders differently from part outside the green borders, gradientally? Also to pick bins which are nearly by green borders and turn them into another colour?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean here by 'gradiently'. Should it vary from blue near the borders at x2 and x3 and green in the center?

Comment: @JohanC I found that `n, bins, patches = plt.hist(prices.tail(1), bins=400, facecolor='#2ab0ff', edgecolor='#e0e0e0', linewidth=0, alpha=0.7)`, `n = n.astype('int')`, and `for i in range(len(patches)): patches[i].set_facecolor(plt.cm.viridis(n[i]/max(n)))` can produce the gradiental colour, but I still need to highlight the bins which correspond to `left_border` and `right_border`

Comment: So, your coloring the bars depending on their height? It can look quite strange when the distribution when there is a lot of variation in the n values.

Comment: Well, variation is nearly by normal distribution, ofcourse some bars in area with most count of distributions are shorter, while other are longer, but in general it gives a clear understanding which range contains the most part of distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact meaning of 'gradiently' here is uncertain to me. Here are some ideas that can serve as a base to create the desired solution.

- `hist` returns the values of each bin, the limits of the bins and the patches that were drawn; you can color the patches depending on their mean x-position
- to create a gradient like effect, the simplest is interpolating linearly between two colors; a function such as `sqrt` can be used to make the effect start quicker
- `axvspan` can draw a vertical span between two given x coordinates; set `zorder=0` to make sure the span stays behind the histogram bars; or set an `alpha=0.3` to draw it as a transparent layer over the bars

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

prices_np = 14*np.random.normal(5, 1, 10000)**2

left_border = 341.086
right_border = 437.177
# line_length = 1099
divisor_tickness = 10
main_color = mcolors.to_rgb('dodgerblue')
highlight_color = mcolors.to_rgb('limegreen')
divisor_color = mcolors.to_rgb('crimson')

binvals, bins, patches = plt.hist(prices_np, bins = 400, color=main_color)

bin_centers = 0.5 * (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])

for p, x in zip(patches, bin_centers):
    #x, _ = p.get_xy()
    #w = p.get_width()
    if left_border < x  < right_border:
        f = 2*min(x-left_border, right_border-x) / (right_border - left_border)
        f = f ** 0.5
        p.set_facecolor([ (h_rgb*f + m_rgb * (1-f))  for m_rgb, h_rgb in zip(main_color, highlight_color)] )
    elif left_border-divisor_tickness < x <= left_border or right_border <= x < right_border + divisor_tickness:
        p.set_facecolor(divisor_color)

plt.axvspan(left_border, right_border, color='lightgoldenrodyellow', zorder=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

To get a smooth gradient depending on the bar heights, a [gaussian kde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) could be useful:

```
kde = gaussian_kde(prices_np)
max_kde = max([kde(x)[0] for x in bin_centers])
for x, p in zip(bin_centers, patches):
    p.set_facecolor(plt.cm.viridis((kde(x)[0] / max_kde) ))
```

[image: using gaussian kde for color]

Comment: Thanks! It's helpfull for solving my problem. Colouring background behing range within borders looks great!